# AngularJS dependency error

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

[image]

I have my app organizad as in the image...I have a dependency problem when i m trying to inject $state in my app.config module as in the second image

[image]

i get the following error :

angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…frontend%2Fassets%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)

can someone tell me if i m wrong in the order of dependencies?

Comment: I have the same problem also if I try to inject $rootScope

Comment: Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured. See more https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: ok thanks. I m pretty new to angular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject `$stateProvider` inside your config function, not `$state` itself.

Comment: if I add $stateProvider then i can not use $state

Comment: Yes, and you would never use instance of your service inside config. Use in in `angular.module('app').run(function(){...});`

Comment: so i have to add my interceptor in run?

Comment: in this case yes. but you have to do it on `Restangular` not on `RestangularProvider` 

`angular.module('app').run(function(Restangular){...});`

Comment: watching at this example, http://beletsky.net/2013/11/simple-authentication-in-angular-dot-js-app.html I can not push the interceptor in the .config block if I define my factory

Comment: sorry for my insistance. but why if I create a factory httpInterceptor and I try to run the following code in the .config:     $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('httpInterceptor'); I get the same error in the original question?

Comment: Because when you push this factory as interceptor `$state` is not initialized yet. If you want to use instances of providers you should add interceptor in `run` function not in `config`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106158/discussion-between-pierpaolo-croce-and-dmitriy-nevzorov).